# Pandas create new column in df2 from another df1 column2 if a value in df1 column1 matches value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I need to compare items in a list to a column in df1 and create new column in df2 with value from a different column on the same row in df1, if there is a match between a list item and the compared df1 column

My code and results

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list elements
new_data = [[10,'a'], [20, 'b'], [30, 'c'], [40, 'd']]
old_data = [['10a','A', 10.05], [22, 'B', 12.10], [40, 'C', 1.10], 
[20, 'D', 8.05], [15, 'E', 9.00]]
lst = [20, 40, 50, 70, '20a']
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Numbers', 'Letters'])
print(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(old_data, columns=['level', 'cap', 'time'])
df2['Exit'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['Letters'] if \
str(x['Numbers']) in lst else 0, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Result

```
level cap   time  Exit
0   10a   A  10.05   0.0
1    22   B  12.10   0.0
2    40   C   1.10   0.0
3    20   D   8.05   0.0
4    15   E   9.00   NaN
```

But Expected

```
level cap   time Exit
0   10a   A  10.05   0
1    22   B  12.10   0
2    40   C   1.10   d
3    20   D   8.05   b
4    15   E   9.00   0
```

I am missing something?

Comment: I don't understand where the list comes into play. If you have df1 and df2 why not just merge [Pandas Merging 101](/q/53645882/15497888) `df2.merge(df1, how='left', left_on='level', right_on='Numbers')`

Comment: `df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Numbers': 'level', 'Letters': 'Exit'}), how='left', on='level').fillna(0)` with cleanup

Comment: The list can contain more values than found in any of the dfs

Comment: But how does that come into play if the Exit column can only get values from `df1`? Or you want the value in the Letters column if it matches any value in the list regardless of if it matches the corresponding value in `df1` Numbers column?

Comment: want to make sure that the values used for matching can be found in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make the Numbers column the index of `df1` with [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the DataFrame with `lst` so that only values that appear in the list remain in the DataFrame. Then [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) *again* with the level column of `df2` and [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to assign the column without index alignment:

```python
df2['Exit'] = (
    df1.set_index('Numbers')
        .reindex(index=lst)  # Ensure only values from list are present
        .reindex(index=df2['level'], fill_value=0)  # Re-align to df2['level'] column
        .to_numpy()  # Ignore index alignment
)
```

`df2`:

```
  level cap   time Exit
0   10a   A  10.05    0
1    22   B  12.10    0
2    40   C   1.10    d
3    20   D   8.05    b
4    15   E   9.00    0
```

---

Alternatively, we can then [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) a restructured `df1` to `df2`.

To restructure `df1` [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `lst` to create the subset only using values from `lst`

```python
(
    df1.set_index('Numbers')
        .reindex(index=lst)
        .rename(columns={'Letters': 'Exit'})
)

        Exit
Numbers     
20         b
40         d
50       NaN
70       NaN
20a      NaN
```

The [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) ensures that the new column appears with the correct name and then [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fix the NaN values.

All together this looks like:

```python
df2 = df2.join(
    df1.set_index('Numbers')
        .reindex(index=lst)
        .rename(columns={'Letters': 'Exit'}),
    how='left',
    on='level'
).fillna({'Exit': 0})
```

`df2`:

```
  level cap   time Exit
0   10a   A  10.05    0
1    22   B  12.10    0
2    40   C   1.10    d
3    20   D   8.05    b
4    15   E   9.00    0
```

---

Yet another option, creating a mapper from the modified `df1` above using [Series.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) and then [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)ping the values back to `df2` level column:

```python
df2['Exit'] = df2['level'].map(
    df1.set_index('Numbers')['Letters']
        .reindex(index=lst)
        .dropna()
        .to_dict()
).fillna(0)
```

`df2`:

```
  level cap   time Exit
0   10a   A  10.05    0
1    22   B  12.10    0
2    40   C   1.10    d
3    20   D   8.05    b
4    15   E   9.00    0
```

---

Setup and version:

```python
import pandas as pd  # version 1.4.3

lst = [20, 40, 50, 70, '20a']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[10, 'a'], [20, 'b'], [30, 'c'], [40, 'd']],
    columns=['Numbers', 'Letters']
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [['10a', 'A', 10.05], [22, 'B', 12.10], [40, 'C', 1.10],
     [20, 'D', 8.05], [15, 'E', 9.00]],
    columns=['level', 'cap', 'time']
)
```

Comment: I appreciate the variety of your answers and the explanations provided. This is really helpful. Seems there are lots of ways to accomplish the task

Comment: NP. It just depends what order you want to do the reshaping and the joining. These should all be functionally equivalent but some may be faster than others depending on scale and shape of actual data.

Comment: I will check to see by how much each one of them scales because of the large size of my data